# Getting "Value does not fall within the expected range" when creating a new discussion with CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, csom

I'm using the SharePoint 2013 client object model.

I'm getting a Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException that says: "Value does not fall within the expected range" when running _context.ExecuteQuery(). The code works as long as I comment out the statement `entry["Author"] = authorValue;`:

```
entry["Body"] = post.Body;
entry["Created"] = post.Created;
entry["Modified"] = post.Modified;

FieldUserValue authorValue = new FieldUserValue();
User author = _context.Web.EnsureUser("Mr. X");
_context.Load(author);
_context.ExecuteQuery();
authorValue.LookupId = author.Id;

entry["Author"] = authorValue;

entry.Update();
_context.ExecuteQuery();
```

"Author" is a valid field name. I also read about increasing "List View Lookup Threshold" to a value of 20 in http://dotnetfollower.com/wordpress/2012/05/sharepoint-value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range-exception-in-spfieldmap-getcolumnnumber/. But that value is already set to 5000.

I also checked the value of `entry["Author"]` without setting it explicitly (`entry["Author"] = authorValue` commented out) by adding this two statements:

```
_context.Load(entry);
_context.ExecuteQuery();
```

It is of type `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue` and it's `LookupId` property value is equal to `authorValue.LookupId`.

What did I miss?

Comment: have you found a resolution for this?  I've got a possibly related issue here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134845/csom-retrieve-list-item-doesnt-show-some-lookup-key-value-pairs